# Python: Problems appending items to a list over loop iteration

Tags: python, list

I'm new to python so I'm a bit confusing how to deal with that.

I'm trying to append items to a list:

```
li = []
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk('/data/disk4/a0050969/sftpcollector/Utils/'):
    for filename in files:
        if filename.endswith(('.log')):
        f = os.path.join(path, filename)
        li.append(f)
print f
```

It gaves me:

> []
>   ['/data/disk4/a0050969/sftpcollector/Utils/brtlvlts0325pl/secondftp_20160608.log']
>   ['/data/disk4/a0050969/sftpcollector/Utils/brtlvlts0325pl/secondftp_20160608.log',
>   '/data/disk4/a0050969/sftpcollector/Utils/brtlvlts0324pl/secondftp_20160608.log']
>   ['/data/disk4/a0050969/sftpcollector/Utils/brtlvlts0325pl/secondftp_20160608.log',
>   '/data/disk4/a0050969/sftpcollector/Utils/brtlvlts0324pl/secondftp_20160608.log',
>   '/data/disk4/a0050969/sftpcollector/Utils/brtlvlts0264co/secondftp_20160608.log',
>   '/data/disk4/a0050969/sftpcollector/Utils/brtlvlts0264co/secondother_20160608.log',
>   '/data/disk4/a0050969/sftpcollector/Utils/brtlvlts0264co/secondhttp_20160608.log']

and I'm expecting just:

> ['/data/disk4/a0050969/sftpcollector/Utils/brtlvlts0325pl/secondftp_20160608.log',
>   '/data/disk4/a0050969/sftpcollector/Utils/brtlvlts0324pl/secondftp_20160608.log',
>   '/data/disk4/a0050969/sftpcollector/Utils/brtlvlts0264co/secondftp_20160608.log',
>   '/data/disk4/a0050969/sftpcollector/Utils/brtlvlts0264co/secondother_20160608.log',
>   '/data/disk4/a0050969/sftpcollector/Utils/brtlvlts0264co/secondhttp_20160608.log']

On the other hand if I do:

```
with open(LOCAL_F_PATH_CTRL+'temp.tmp', "w") as dd:
    for path, subdirs, files in os.walk('/data/disk4/a0050969/sftpcollector/Utils/'):
        for filename in files:
            if filename.endswith(('.log')):
                f = os.path.join(path, filename)
                dd.write(str(f)+os.linesep)
```

It writes the way I need:

> /data/disk4/a0050969/sftpcollector/Utils/brtlvlts0325pl/secondftp_20160608.log
>   /data/disk4/a0050969/sftpcollector/Utils/brtlvlts0324pl/secondftp_20160608.log
>   /data/disk4/a0050969/sftpcollector/Utils/brtlvlts0264co/secondftp_20160608.log
>   /data/disk4/a0050969/sftpcollector/Utils/brtlvlts0264co/secondother_20160608.log
>   /data/disk4/a0050969/sftpcollector/Utils/brtlvlts0264co/secondhttp_20160608.log

I cannot figure out what's wrong with the code.

Comment: @LPK thx for editing.

Comment: Are you sure your indentation is correct on the first one? last three lines seems a bit off. Also, seems like you want to print li in your first one. Not f.

Comment: Just use `li.extend(f)` instead of `li.append(f)`, obviously after correcting the indentation!

Comment: @ Lafexlos, typo error. thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The indentation in your first snippet is definitely wrong. After the `if`, at least on line needs be indented.

Could it be that you are mixing tabs and spaces in your code? This sometimes makes for very hard to detect bugs. I recommend configuring your editor to automatically insert spaces when you hit the `Tab` key.

Comment: thx I'm using sublime text 3 and settings seems to be ok.     // The number of spaces a tab is considered equal to
    "tab_size": 4,

Comment: But does it really insert 4 spaces rather than a tab when you press the key? Your code should not contain any tabs at all.
You need to have `"translate_tabs_to_spaces": true`

Comment: So it was exactly that! O couldn't realize that tabs vesus "\n" in my code could do that. Basic mistake. OMG.

Answer (score 0):

Python is very serious about indentation, hence in the first example of your code, since the

```
f = os.path.join(path, filename)
        li.append(f)
```

is in line with the `if` condition, the block of code run only once and not in the loop. If its in the loop, as shown in your second example, it will append it to the list properly

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is just a formatting error when you posted the code but the below lines are not indented properly under the if statement. This may be your issue.

```
f = os.path.join(path, filename)
        li.append(f)
```